# Why some threads don't receive pthread_cond_broadcast?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, handler, broadcast

I have a threadpool of workers. Each worker executes this routine:

```
void* worker(void* args){
  ...
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

  while (queue == NULL && stop == 0){
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
  }

  el = pop(queue);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

  ...
}
```

main thread:

```
int main(){

   ...
   while (stop == 0){
     ...
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);  
     insert(queue, el);
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
     ...
   }
...
}
```

Then I have a signal handler that executes this code when it receives a signal:

```
void exit_handler(){
    stop = 1;   
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); 
}
```

I have omitted declarations and initialization, but the original code has them.

After a signal is received most of the time it's all ok, but sometimes it seems that some worker threads stay in the wait loop because they don't see that the variable stop is changed and/or they are not waken up by the broadcast.

So the threads never end.
What I am missing?

**EDIT**: stop=1 moved inside the critical section in exit_handler. The issue remains.

**EDIT2**: I was executing the program on a VM with Ubuntu. Since the code appears to be totally right I tried to change VM and OS (XUbuntu) and now it seems to work correctly. Still don't know why, anyone has an idea?

Comment: `stop = 1` should be executed within the mutex-protected section.  This is a comment because I can't see how that causes the issue you're seeing, though.

Comment: I tried, but the issue still remaine. I'm running the program on a virtual machine, is it possible that it can cause some strange problem? Because, really, the code seems correct.

Comment: could you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As noted, my answer is wrong, but I'm intrigued by this problem since I'm working on something similar (except I'm using `phtread_cond_signal` instead of `pthread_cond_broadcast`). I've written some test code that I think does what you're describing but I don't think I'm seeing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Some guessing here, but it's too long for a comment, so if this is wrong, I will delete.  I think you may have a misconception about how `pthread_cond_broadcast` works (at least something I've been burned with in the past).  From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_broadcast):</s>

> The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` function shall unblock all threads
>   currently blocked on the specified condition variable cond.

Ok, that make sense, `_broadcast` awakens all threads currently blocked on `cond`.  *However*, only *one* of the awakened threads will then be able to lock the mutex after they're all awoken.  Also from the man page:

> The **thread(s)** that are unblocked shall contend for the mutex according
>   to the scheduling policy (if applicable), and as if each had called
>   `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

So this means that if 3 threads are blocked on `cond` and `_broadcast` is called, all 3 threads will wake up, but only 1 can grab the mutex.  The other 2 will still be stuck in `pthread_cond_wait`, waiting on a signal. Because of this, they don't see `stop` set to 1, and `exit_handler` (I'm assuming a Ctrl+c software signal?) is done signaling, so the remaining threads that lost the `_broadcast` competition are stuck in limbo, waiting on a signal that will never come, and unable to read that the `stop` flag has been set.

I think there are 2 options to work-around/fix this:

1. Use [`pthread_cond_timedwait`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait).  Even without being signaled, this will return from waiting at the specified time interval, see that `stop == 1`, and then exit.
2. Add `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast` at the end of your `worker` function.  This way, right before a thread exits, it will signal the `cond` variable allowing any other waiting threads to grab the mutex and finish processing.  There is no harm in signaling a conditional variable if no threads are waiting on it, so this should be fine even for the last thread.

---

**EDIT**: Here is an MCVE that proves (as far as I can tell) that my answer above is wrong, heh.  As soon as I press Ctrl+c, the program exits "immediately", which says to me all the threads are quickly acquiring the mutex after the broadcast, seeing that `stop` is false, and exiting.  Then `main` joins on the threads and it's process over.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define NUM_THREADS 3
#define STACK_SIZE 10

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
volatile bool stop = false;
int stack[STACK_SIZE] = { 0 };
int sp = 0; // stack pointer,, also doubles as the current stack size

void SigHandler(int sig)
{
  if (sig == SIGINT)
  {
    stop = true;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Received unexcepted signal %d\n", sig);
  }
}

void* worker(void* param)
{
  long tid = (long)(param);
  while (stop == false)
  {
    // acquire the lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    while (sp <= 0)  // sp should never be < 0
    {
      // there is no data in the stack to consume, wait to get signaled
      // this unlocks the mutex when it is called, and locks the
      // mutex before it returns
      pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
    }

    // when we get here we should be guaranteed sp >= 1
    printf("thread %ld consuming stack[%d] = %d\n", tid, sp-1, stack[sp-1]);
    sp--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

    int sleepVal = rand() % 10;
    printf("thread %ld sleeping for %d seconds...\n", tid, sleepVal);
    sleep(sleepVal);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (long i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
  {
    int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, worker, (void*)i);
    if (rc != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread %ld\n", i);
    }
  }

  while (stop == false)
  {
    // produce data in bursts
    int numValsToInsert = rand() % (STACK_SIZE - sp);
    printf("main producing %d values\n", numValsToInsert);
    // acquire the lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

    for (int i=0; i<numValsToInsert; i++)
    {
      // produce values for the stack
      int val = rand() % 10000;
      // I think this should already be guaranteed..?
      if (sp+1 < STACK_SIZE)
      {
        printf("main pushing stack[%d] = %d\n", sp, val);
        stack[sp++] = val;
        // signal the workers that data is ready
        //printf("main signaling threads...\n");
        //pthread_cond_signal(&c);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("stack full!\n");
      }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

    // signal the workers that data is ready
    printf("main signaling threads...\n");
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);  

    int sleepVal = 1;//rand() % 5;
    printf("main sleeping for %d seconds...\n", sleepVal);
    sleep(sleepVal);    
  }


  for (long i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect: "The other 2 will still be stuck in pthread_cond_wait, waiting on a signal." They will not be waiting for a signal. They are no longer blocked on the condvar. They are only waiting for the mutex to become available.

Comment: @R.. heh that is the part I was most unsure about, as I'm not familiar with the internals of `pthread_cond_wait`. So this is completely wrong then? If they're no longer waiting on a signal, but waiting to lock the mutex, each thread that was awoken with `_broadcast` should eventually acquire the mutex as the ones who acquired it before will release it before they exit? If so, then my answer does not correctly address what the OP has described.

Comment: That's not the internals, it's the abstract interface. And yes, unless I'm missing something this answer is largely wrong. They should all eventually acquire the mutex. If they don't it's either because the first thread to acquire it is never releasing it, or because the program exits before they all get a chance to acquire it. Another possibility is that they're all looping and waiting on the condvar again because something the first thread to acquire the mutex does causes the predicate to become false again.

Comment: Also note that the usual way to broadcast is to unlock mutex before broadcasting. If you read the documentation carefully, doing it in that order may be slightly more efficient on some pthreads implementations, and is completely safe as per the API.

Comment: @R.. and Erik, Thanks for the input, I need to put together some test code.

Comment: @R.. You probably don't care but I've added an MCVE that proves (as far as I can tell) my answer is wrong you are right. I think the code accurately duplicates what the OP is describing (except I'm not signaling `c` in `SigHandler`), but perhaps not. When I run this code it immediately exits on Ctrl+c, so all worker threads must be acquiring the mutex and finishing their work as you say. Thanks for that, this was a case where I learned more from answering rather than asking. OP needs to provide an MCVE, I can't duplicate the problem. I'll delete this answer in a couple of days.

Comment: @ErikAlapää thanks for the input, just notifying you of the above in case you're interested. Two things I don't like about SO.. no line numbers on code and the inability to notify multiple folks in one comment. That should at least be a rep accomplishment or something.

Comment: @yano: Thanks for the update. I actually do like to solve these kinds of questions and improve the body of good information on C/POSIX interfaces ppl find when searching; that's why I comment or answer.

Comment: @yano I think my issue will remain a mistery... my code is very similiar to yours but it's part of a very large program with many client that send requests to the server, so maybe there are some particular problems with the threads interleaving.
By the way this problem shows up only few times in many tests and I noticed that the success rate is increased when I moved the stop=1 inside the lock section.

Comment: I felt it would be helpful to strikethrough the original incorrect answer, because I was left confused and worried until I got to your edit. So I suggested an edit. Feel free to reject it if you want. However, I think it would be helpful to put an edit at the top saying the original answer is wrong, so the reader doesn't have to wait until they read most of the answer to find out it is wrong.